# pandas corr table column name behavior

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm calculating a corr table in pandas,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 6))

c = df.corr()
```

But when I try to change the name of the columns,

```
c.columns.name = 'col'
```

I get this,

```
col         0         1         2         3         4         5
col                                                            
0    1.000000  0.051975 -0.171113  0.196975  0.057700 -0.008229
1    0.051975  1.000000 -0.055077 -0.298845 -0.642585 -0.465581
2   -0.171113 -0.055077  1.000000 -0.591092  0.051866  0.584618
3    0.196975 -0.298845 -0.591092  1.000000 -0.327067 -0.059618
4    0.057700 -0.642585  0.051866 -0.327067  1.000000  0.359508
5   -0.008229 -0.465581  0.584618 -0.059618  0.359508  1.000000
```

Also,

```
print c.index.name

col
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform the `corr` method and produce the correlation matrix, you end up with a square matrix where the columns are the same as the rows.  It's convenient to assign both the `index` and `columns` to be the same object.  So `c.index` and `c.columns` are pointing to the same thing.  To break this link, you need to make one a copy of itself.

```
c.index = c.index.copy()

c.columns.name = 'col'

print c

col         0         1         2         3         4         5
0    1.000000 -0.208454  0.015920  0.397915  0.283203 -0.433138
1   -0.208454  1.000000  0.384982 -0.881456  0.037897  0.430109
2    0.015920  0.384982  1.000000 -0.308990 -0.744234 -0.078394
3    0.397915 -0.881456 -0.308990  1.000000 -0.149954 -0.690244
4    0.283203  0.037897 -0.744234 -0.149954  1.000000  0.325190
5   -0.433138  0.430109 -0.078394 -0.690244  0.325190  1.000000
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are just after renaming the index, you can do it this way:

```
In [235]: c.rename_axis('col')
Out[235]:
            0         1         2         3         4         5
col
0    1.000000 -0.406438  0.715564 -0.354630 -0.313099 -0.723027
1   -0.406438  1.000000 -0.512059 -0.369779 -0.201501  0.445913
2    0.715564 -0.512059  1.000000  0.300887  0.105123 -0.558040
3   -0.354630 -0.369779  0.300887  1.000000  0.750460  0.295423
4   -0.313099 -0.201501  0.105123  0.750460  1.000000 -0.004003
5   -0.723027  0.445913 -0.558040  0.295423 -0.004003  1.000000
```

Comment: Super useful.  Thank you.